# Understanding Records.json data points from google geo takeout

Tags: gps, geolocation

Within the records.json file from Google Location data takeout, there are activity types with accuracy values.

I am trying to understand how accurate an activity type of, On Foot / walking will be.
How is this calculated ?
GPS fixes via wifi scan ?
In vehicle activity?

I am a digital forensic investigator.

Comment: I would expect that "foot/walking" is based on the movement speed may be correlated with the acceleration sensor data.

Answer (score 1):

strong textLocation accuracy is controlled by GPS, Wifi and Cell towers.  For it to be more accurate, you need to to turn on `High Accuracy Mode`.

> How Maps finds your current location
> Maps estimates where you are from sources like:
>
> **GPS**: Maps uses satellites to know your location up to around 20 meters. When you're inside buildings or underground, the GPS is sometimes inaccurate.
> **Wi-Fi**: The location of nearby Wi-Fi networks helps Maps know where you are.
> **Cell tower**: Your connection to mobile data can be accurate up to a few thousand meters.

From [Find & improve your location’s accuracy](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform=Android)

**Step count** is measured vis silicon devices on the phone and they are pretty accurate.  However distance travelled using step-count data is dependent on the user entering their height.  From this apps such as `Samsung Health` work out your stride.  This is an estimate at best.

**Walking a track**
Google maps already knows how long a track or walking route or roads are.  If you are waking or running these, then it is exact +/- Location accuracy.  Pure GPS error is about 5m in clear sky.  I have seen figures of sub-metre accuracy with the use of Wifi and Cell Towers.  But I cant find any references right now.